# ZipException: duplicate entry during Android Build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, ros

I'm getting this exception during my build.

```
:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/io/comparator/DefaultFileComparator.class

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I've traced it to a conflict between these two libraries.

```
compile 'org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava_geometry:0.2.1'
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
```

I have seen other similar problems solved by using "exclude group:" or something similar in the build.gradle. However, they never show how to find what group to exclude. If that's even the right answer.

Here is the full list of dependencies.

[PocketBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tesseractmobile.pocketbot)

```
ext {
    playServicesVersion = '9.4.0'
    supportLibVersion = '24.2.0'
    qbSdkVersion = '2.6'
}

dependencies {
        compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibVersion}"
        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
        //Android ros support - https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/tree/indigo
        compile project(':AndroidRosJava')
        //Serial Library to talk to Arduino over USB OTG
        compile project(':usbSerialForAndroid')
        //Protobuf
        compile files('libs/protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar')
        //Crashlytics
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.6@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        //Face Tracking
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:${playServicesVersion}"
        //User authentication
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${playServicesVersion}"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:${playServicesVersion}"
        //App Invites
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:${playServicesVersion}"
        //Nearby Connections - Local networking
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:${playServicesVersion}"
        //RecyclerView
        compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
        //WebRTC
        compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:${qbSdkVersion}@aar"
        compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:${qbSdkVersion}@aar") {
            transitive = true
        }
        compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:${qbSdkVersion}@aar"
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
        //AI
        compile 'ai.api:sdk:1.9.0@aar'
        //TODO: Disabled until http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195771/zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-android-build
        compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
        //Firebase - cloud data storage
        compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${playServicesVersion}"
        compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:${playServicesVersion}"
        compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:${playServicesVersion}"
        compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:${playServicesVersion}"
        //Bluetooth beacon detection
        compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.9.1'
        //Houndify - Voice recognition and backup AI
        compile ('hound.android:hound-sdk:0.2.15@aar'){
            transitive=true
        }
        compile ('hound.android:phrasespotter:1.4.0'){
            transitive=true
        }
        //Testing
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibVersion}"
        // UI testing with Espresso
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
        androidTestCompile 'tools.fastlane:screengrab:0.3.2'
        // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

AndroidRosJava (Started after adding this project library)

```
dependencies {
  compile 'org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava_geometry:[0.2,0.3)'
  compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibVersion}"
  compile 'org.ros.rosjava_messages:visualization_msgs:[1.11,1.12)'
  compile "org.ros.rosjava_messages:diagnostic_msgs:[1.11,1.12)"
  compile "org.ros.rosjava_messages:sensor_msgs:[1.11,1.12)"
}
```

Comment: "I've traced it to a conflict between these two libraries" -- I do not see that class in [the JAR file for your ROS dependency](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/blob/master/org/ros/rosjava_core/rosjava_geometry/0.2.1/rosjava_geometry-0.2.1.jar).

Comment: if you remove line `compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'` is your program still compiling?  I think that another library may use this one

Comment: @CommonsWare I added the full list of dependencies. I thought I knew what was causing it because it happened after adding the ROS libraries.

Comment: @piotrek1543 commons-io is used by api.ai. I have just disabled the feature for now. It would compile but the throw a run time exception when I removed commons-io.